# What's the difference between "in itself", "by itself" and "in and of itself"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

> A. This **in itself** requires investigation.
>
> B. Energy **by itself** is useless.
>
> C. That **in and of itself** is interesting.

What is their meaning and how to use them correctly?

**Subquestion:** Let's say I want to buy a B12 vitamin formula and the pharmacist is giving me a B-Complex bottle of the supplement. Can we say: I'm looking for B12 formula by itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**by itself** means "alone, unaccompanied".

**in itself** means "not needing other things".

**in and of itself** means "when considered in isolation".

> The pony, standing by itself in the paddock, looked rather forlorn.
>
> This deed, in itself, is an impeachable offense.
>
> This action, in and of itself, does not constitute obstruction of justice, but when seen in the context of other actions, a pattern of behavior emerges which rises to that offense.

Yes, you could say "I'd like some B12, by itself" or "B12, just by itself".